# Error generating a django form with materialize

Tags: django

When I use a template to fill out a form I cannot use the checkboxes, because they come out as if they were disabled and I cannot select them and the password is not saved with a hash if not as simple text

I have a form code with a user model with AbstractUser and signals to create multiple roles:

```
            class User(AbstractUser):
            is_administrator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
            is_satellite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

            def get_administrator(self):
                administrator = None
                if hasattr(self, 'administrator'):
                    administrator = self.administrator
                return administrator

            def get_satellite(self):
                satellite = None
                if hasattr(self, 'satellite'):
                    satelite = self.satellite
                return satellite

            def __str__(self):
                return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

            class Meta:
                db_table = 'auth_user'


        class Administrator(models.Model):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            business_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


        class Satellite(models.Model):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            business_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


        @receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
        def assign_role(sender, instance, **kwargs):
            if instance.is_administrator:
                administrator = Administrator(user=instance)
                administrator.save()
            elif instance.is_satellite:
                satellite = Satellite(user=instance)
                satellite.save()
```

And the form is as follows:

```
        from django import forms
        from .models import (
            User,
        )


        class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                          'password', 'is_active', 'is_administrator', 
                          'is_satelite']
                labels = {
                    'username': 'Username',
                    'first_name': 'Name',
                    'last_name': 'Surname',
                    'email': 'Email',
                    'password': 'Password',
                    'is_active': 'State',
                    'is_administrator': 'Administrator',
                    'is_satellite': 'Satellite',
                },
                widgets = {
                    'username': forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={
                            'placeholder': 'Username',
                            'id': 'username'
                        }
                    ),
                    'first_name': forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={
                            'placeholder': 'Name',
                            'id': 'first_name'
                        }
                    ),
                    'last_name': forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={
                            'placeholder': 'Surname',
                            'id': 'last_name'
                        }
                    ),
                    'email': forms.EmailInput(
                        attrs={
                            'placeholder': 'Email',
                            'id': 'email'
                        }
                    ),
                    'password': forms.PasswordInput(
                        attrs={
                            'placeholder': 'Password',
                            'id': 'password'
                        }
                    ),
                     'is_active': forms.CheckboxInput(
                    attrs={
                        'placeholder': 'State',
                        'id': 'is_active'
                    }
                ),
                'is_administrator': forms.CheckboxInput(
                    attrs={
                        'placeholder': 'state',
                        'id': 'is_administrator'
                    }
                ),
                'is_satellite': forms.CheckboxInput(
                    attrs={
                        'placeholder': 'State',
                        'id': 'is_satellite'
                    }
                ),
```

And I am using the template to use the entire form:

```
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-title">New User Registration</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <form class="col s12" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                        <a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}" class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cancel</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat right"><i
                                class="material-icons left">how_to_reg</i>Register</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What happens is that when the form is generated, the checkbox does not give me the option to activate or deactivate it but that only happens when I apply the materialize styles because without them I do not generate any errors in the template and I get the password without its format and treat it as if it were any text and it is generated without its hash.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add the password from the django form so add the password form field like this

```
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

and for the checkbox this problem in materialize not in django try to add this to your css

```
.input-field label {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

it should fix your issue , hope it works ^_^

Comment: thank you very much and the password could be resolved but not the checkbox

Comment: I updated my answer and added a possible solution to the checkbox hope it works and do not forget to check my answer as the best answer ^_^